# Containerized Nginx Plus is Unable to Open or Rename Okta JWK File

Tags: docker, openid-connect, okta, jwk, nginx-plus

Why is my instance of Nginx Plus unable to access a JSON Web Key (JWK) file from Okta?

This instance of Nginx Plus was containerized with a `Dockerfile` similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/nginx-gists/36e97fc87efb5cf0039978c8e41a34b5#file-dockerfile-alpine) official `Dockerfile.alpine` direct from Nginx, with the following differences:

```docker
. . .

COPY ["cert.pem", "cert.key", "/"]

. . .

RUN . . .

. . .

        nginx-plus-module-njs \

. . .

RUN ["rm", "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"]

. . .

COPY ["frontend.conf", "openid_connect.js", "openid_connect.server_conf", "openid_connect_configuration.conf", "/etc/nginx/conf.d/"]

. . .

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off; load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;"]
```

`frontend.conf`, `openid_connect.js`, `openid_connect.server_conf` and `openid_connect_configuration.conf` were all copied from `nginx-openid-connect`, found [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-openid-connect).

`frontend.conf`, `openid_connect.server_conf` and `openid_connect_configuration.conf` were all configured properly, following [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-openid-connect#configuring-nginx-plus) part of the installation process.

Nginx Plus was configured properly in the Okta Admin Console as an OIDC application.

When I enter the static external IP address pointing at my containerized Nginx Plus instance in a fresh browser session, I am redirected to `https://$OKTA_DOMAIN_NAME.okta.com` and prompted to login.  After correct credentials are entered, I can see the following in the Nginx Plus logs:

```sh
. . .
1970/01/01 00:00:01 [alert] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/oidc_id_tokens.json.tmp" failed (13: Permission denied)
. . .
```

adding `oidc_id_tokens.json.tmp` with the following `COPY` instruction to the `Dockerfile`:

```docker
COPY --chown=nginx:nginx ["empty.file", "/etc/nginx/conf.d/oidc_id_tokens.json.tmp"]
```

produced another similar error after redeployment and another login flow:

```sh
. . .
1970/01/01 00:00:01 [crit] 1#1: rename() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/oidc_id_tokens.json.tmp" to "/etc/nginx/conf.d/oidc_id_tokens.json" failed (13: Permission denied)
. . .
```

How would I allow Nginx Plus access to the JWK file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the "Troubleshooting" header from the `nginx-openid-connect` repository you linked, the final bullet underneath "Authentication is successful but browser shows too many redirects" instructs you to ensure that the `nginx` user has access to the JWK file.

This is **not** referring to an Okta user or account; this is referring to the `nginx` user within your Docker image.  If you:

```sh
docker run \
--entrypoint="" \
--interactive \
--tty \
$NGINX_PLUS_IMAGE_ID \
cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

#=>

user  nginx;
. . .
```

you can see that the base Nginx config. file uses the `nginx` user instead of `root`.

We *should* give `nginx` access to all files within the `/etc/nginx` directory with the:

```docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "nginx:nginx", "/etc/nginx"]
```

`Dockerfile` instruction.